# Store connection string outside version control

Tags: git, asp.net-core, .net-core-configuration

How do you go about database connection string handling in version control? As I understand, connection strings are usually held in appsettings.json, does that mean the best practice would be to add appsettings.json to .gitignore? I also have API keys, so would it be sensible to create a .env and add connection strings and API keys there?

Comment: ASP.NET Core configuration already offers a way [to store secrets outside version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows) using the Secrets tool

Answer (score 0):

When you use Visual Studio, You can right click the solution Name and select `Manage User Secrets`.

[image]

It will generate a `secrets.json` file, You can configure your connection string here and read it as in `appsettings.json`. This file is in the specified path `Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json` in you local, So When you upload your project to Github, This file will not be uploaded together.

If you use another IDE like `Rider`, You need install plugin to achieve this function.